# How can I get a list of all classes that inherit a specific class using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I am trying to implement event-listener functionality in my asp.Net MVC application.

I created two abstract/base classes like so

```
public abstract class Event
{

}

public abstract class Listener<T>  where T : Event
{
      public abstract void Handle(T @event);
}
```

Then I have other classes that inheres the listener class like so

```
public class SecondClass : Listener<UserWasRegistred>
{
    public override void Handle(UserWasRegistred @event)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine( @event.User.FullName + " was registered!!" );
    }
}

public class ThirdClass : Listener<UserWasRegistred>
{
      //....
}
```

Finally, here is the implementation of the `Event` class (i.e.`UserWasRegistred`)

```
public class UserWasRegistred : Event
{
     public AspNetUser User { get; set; }

     public UserWasRegistred(AspNetUser user)
     {
           User = user;
     }
}
```

I want to be able to search every loaded `dll` and find both `SecondClass` and `ThirdClass` somehow. "The common factor here is that both listeners inherit "Listener" abstract class.

Here is what I tried

```
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAvailableTypesFromType<T>() where T : class
    {
        List<Type> found = new List<Type>();

        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            Type typeOfListener = typeof(T);
            try
            {
                found.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => typeOfListener.IsAssignableFrom(x)).ToList());
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
            {
                found.AddRange(ex.Types.Where(x => x != null && typeOfListener.IsAssignableFrom(x)));
            }


        }

        return found.ToList();
    }
```

Then I call the method like so

```
IEnumerable<Type> found = GetAvailableTypesFromType<Listener>();
```

However, by code is not finding any class.

How can I correctly search the assemblies and find all classes that inherit the type that I pass to my method?

Comment: just a wild guess, but shouldn't you look for `GetAvailableTypesFromType<Listener<SOMETYPE>>();` instead of `GetAvailableTypesFromType<Listener>();`?

Comment: I don't know SOMETYPE. I just know that SOMETYPE inherits Listener. That's why I want to search for any class that inherits Listener

Comment: `public abstract class Listener<T>  where T : Event` so I meant you should be looking for all classes that derive from `Listener<EventType>` instead of looking for classes that derive from `Listener`. I am not sure you can omit the generic parameter. so your call would look like `GetAvailableTypesFromType<Listener<EventType>>();` ... or in your particular case `GetAvailableTypesFromType<Listener<UserWasRegistred>>();`

Comment: the problem is that I don't know the actual EventType when I need to call that method.

Comment: then I would try to first generate a list L of all types that derive from 'Event' (the generic Parameter of 'Listener<Event>') and in a second step 'foreach Type T in L GetAvailableTypesTypesFromType<Listener<T>>();'. what you are looking for should be the union of all GetAvailableTypes-calls